# Dspace installed successfully but not displaying pages after deployment

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, dspace

I installed dspace on my windows 7 machine and everything works fine.Even the admin account was created.But after deploying it on my tomcat it gives 404 error.I followed installation tutorial given on dspace website.Am I missing something.Please help

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow the steps in deploying web applications? There are two techniques in having Tomcat serve up your web applications.

Below was taken from [DSpace online documentation](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC4x/Installing+DSpace):

- *Technique A.* Tell your Tomcat/Jetty/Resin installation where to find
  your DSpace web application(s). As an example, in the directory
  [tomcat]/conf/Catalina/localhost you could add files similar to the
  following (but replace [dspace]with your installation location):

  **DEFINE A CONTEXT FOR DSpace XML User Interface: xmlui.xml**

  `<?xml version='1.0'?>
  <Context
  docBase="[dspace]/webapps/xmlui"
  debug="0"
  reloadable="true"
  cachingAllowed="false"/>`
- *Technique B.* Simple and complete. You copy only (or all) of the
  DSpace Web application(s) you wish to use from the [dspace]/webapps
  directory to the appropriate directory in your Tomcat/Jetty/Resin
  installation. For example: cp -R [dspace]/webapps/* [tomcat]/webapps*
  (This will copy all the web applications to Tomcat). cp -R
  [dspace]/webapps/jspui [tomcat]/webapps* (This will copy only the
  jspui web application to Tomcat.)

Also check your Tomcat logs for any errors.

Answer (score 0):

what is your dspace version? im use 5.4

```
[dspace-source] mvn package
```

all success!

```
[dspace-source/dspace/target/dspace-installer]ant fresh_install
```

all success!

Init database[optional]

```
c:/dspace-installed/bin dspace-migrate

c:/dspace-installed/bin create-administrator
```

success!

copy all or the essentials[JSPUI,XMLUI,OAI,SOLR] app from `[Dspace-installed/webapps]` to `tomcat-webapps`

start tomcat.be happy!